# Does sysfs procfs devtmpfs mounted by kernel?

Tags: kernel, boot, systemd

I'm looking into systemd.

I thought systemd would mount sysfs(/sys), procfs(/proc), devtmpfs(/dev) during booting after kernel initialization.

But my systemd debugging log show that systemd doesn't mount such file systems.(it only mounts cgroups, securityfs, etc...)

**By when, and whom does such file system is mounted? Does kernel mount sys, proc, dev?**

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those are mounted by systemd PID1, see  src/core/mount-setup.c in the systemd sources.

Comment: yes systemd tries to mount sysfs and procfs. But in archlinux, initramfs already mount them earlier than systemd

Answer (score 2):

First point: the Linux kernel can't mount pseudo-filesystems at user-level. That's also the reason why, for example, all entries in `dev/` must be created by a user-level counterpart (which does not happens for `proc/` and `sys/` where the kernel is capable of creating the entries on the mounted filesystem).

In Linux distributions the mounting of pseudo-filesystems is typically done at user-level by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev). Of course, the kernel must have been configured for  *supporting* these filesystems (otherwise, mounting won't be possible).

Comment: So, do you mean that those pseudo-filesystem shall be mounted by user process?(such as udevd or systemd, etc..)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: But It seems that several pseudo-filesystems are mounted by kernel. There is several mount() functions in kernel source.(fs/sysfs/mount.c, fs/proc/root.c). Are these function actually mount sysfs and procfs?