# if there is no sysfs in /etc/fstab, how sysfs is mounted?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, mount, sysfs

If I type $mount on shell, it shows several mount point

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sys on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3030352k,nr_inodes=757588,mode=755)
....
....
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=606608k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
```

I searched web and it says i could setup mount point by editing fatab.**(like sysfs /sys sysfs noauto 0 0)**
**but in my /etc/fstab, there is no such description about sysfs, it only has descrption about /dev/sda1.**

Then, how does my linux understand sysfs mount point? and who mounts it?

Comment: You could mount a file system by a command or a syscall (without ` fstab` knowing it). I guess that `/sys` is mounted by `systemd` or `udev`

Comment: i thought that too, now i'm looking into systemd source code. and the log shows me that systemd failed to mount sysfs and procfs in mount_setup_early() function. It meas systemd doesn't mount sysfs and profs. Do you have any idea what mount such pseudo filesystem during booting?

Answer (score 0):

FYI:
[Does sysfs procfs devtmpfs mounted by kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306899/does-sysfs-procfs-devtmpfs-mounted-by-kernel/34347490#34347490)

systemd tries to mount, but earlier than that, initramfs mount it.